# Why won't vyatta allow SMTP through my firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, nat, vyatta

I am setting up a vyatta router on VMware ESXi,

But I see to have hit a major snag, I could not get my firewall and NAT to work correctly.

I am not sure what was wrong with NAT but it "seems" to be working now. But the firewall is not allowing traffic from my WAN interface (eth0) to my LAN (eth1). I can confirm its the firewall because I disabled all firewall rules and everything worked with just NAT. If put the firewalls (WAN and LAN) back in place nothing can get through to port 25.

I am not really sure what the issue could be I am using pretty basic firewall rules, I wrote the rules while looking at the vyatta docs so unless there is something odd with the documentation they "should" be working.

Here is my NAT rules so far;

```
vyatta@gateway# show service nat
 rule 20 {
     description "Zimbra SNAT #1"
     outbound-interface eth0
     outside-address {
         address 74.XXX.XXX.XXX
     }
     source {
         address 10.0.0.17
     }
     type source
 }
 rule 21 {
     description "Zimbra SMTP #1"
     destination {
         address 74.XXX.XXX.XXX
         port 25
     }
     inbound-interface eth0
     inside-address {
         address 10.0.0.17
     }
     protocol tcp
     type destination
 }
 rule 100 {
     description "Default LAN -> WAN"
     outbound-interface eth0
     outside-address {
         address 74.XXX.XXX.XXX
     }
     source {
         address 10.0.0.0/24
     }
     type source
 }
```

Then here is my firewall rules, this is where I believe the problem is.

```
vyatta@gateway# show firewall
 all-ping enable
 broadcast-ping disable
 conntrack-expect-table-size 4096
 conntrack-hash-size 4096
 conntrack-table-size 32768
 conntrack-tcp-loose enable
 ipv6-receive-redirects disable
 ipv6-src-route disable
 ip-src-route disable
 log-martians enable
 name LAN_in {
     rule 100 {
         action accept
         description "Default LAN -> any"
         protocol all
         source {
             address 10.0.0.0/24
         }
     }
 }
 name LAN_out {
 }
 name LOCAL {
     rule 100 {
         action accept
         state {
             established enable
         }
     }
 }
 name WAN_in {
     rule 20 {
         action accept
         description "Allow SMTP connections to MX01"
         destination {
             address 74.XXX.XXX.XXX
             port 25
         }
         protocol tcp
     }
     rule 100 {
         action accept
         description "Allow established connections back through"
         state {
             established enable
         }
     }
 }
 name WAN_out {
 }
 receive-redirects disable
 send-redirects enable
 source-validation disable
 syn-cookies enable
```

**SIDENOTE**

To test for open ports I have using this website, http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, it showed port 25 as open without the firewall rules and closed with the firewall rules.

**UPDATE**

Just to see if the firewall was working properly I made a rule to block SSH from the WAN interface. When I checked for port 22 on my primary WAN address it said it was still open even though I outright blocked the port.

Here is the rule I used;

```
 rule 21 {
     action reject
     destination {
         address 74.219.80.163
         port 22
     }
     protocol tcp
 }
```

So now I am convinced either I am doing something wrong or the firewall is not working like it should.

Answer (score 1):

Its working the way it should. Are you applying your firewall rules to zones or interfaces? If you are fconfiguring your rules against zones, you havae to make zone policies also. ie WAN-LOCAL,

Comment: I am applying my rules to interfaces not zones.